# Send to Messenger Button on Safari does not send webhook event

Tags: facebook, safari, facebook-messenger, facebook-webhooks

I have a 'Send to Messenger' button on my app. It use to work just fine earlier. But now it does not work on Safari on Mac & iOS. 
It works on Chrome perfectly, but **when clicked from Safari, Facebook is not sending event on my Webhook.**

Screenshot below: On Safari I also get a specific page after user clicks on authentication " Tap to go back to URL".

[Image where users click on send to messenger button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbzLc.png) 
[User is asked to Authenticate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2jtT.png) 
[Tap to go back to URL screenshot - Likely Culprit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjdYn.png) 
[Button Status shown approved, but in reality its not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Yh1.png)

Comment: Possible reason :

`Exception with thrown value: SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://alpha.lvh.me:3000". The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.`

Comment: But it still works on Chrome. In exact same setting

Comment: Additional Information: If I have already authorized the page, it works just fine, since there is no pop up.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? Facing a similar issue =/

If I use the site using https the only caught exception is:
`The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.`

That error occurs on opening the confirmation modal, and no exceptions are thrown afterwards

Answer (score 0):

The error message given to you is stating the issue:

> The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

When you use the Send To Messenger plugin there are some requirements for your own domain. See the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/send-to-messenger-plugin#requirements). One if these is that you must [whitelist your domain](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting#requirements). It states:

> Use a fully qualified domain name, such as https://www.messenger.com/. IP addresses and localhost are not supported for whitelisting.

You are serving your application using HTTP from http://alpha.lvh.me:3000 but you must serve it using HTTPS. It's also not clear from their requirements if you can use a port number or not but I think you'd be better looking at [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) for local development.

[Edit] I think it's probably an issue with the content security policy (CSP) on Safari. Some reading about it [here](https://scotthelme.co.uk/safari-doesnt-like-csp/).